# Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'lbDatabase' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm working on a fingerprint and I need to make this operation and I get an error, and don't know how to fix it

```
 private void doVerify(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs args)
    {

        VerificationResult verificationResult = new VerificationResult();

        for (int i = 0; i < lbDatabase.Items.Count || verificationResult.score > 0; i++)
        {

            lbDatabase.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { lbDatabase.SelectedItem = i; }));    
            verificationResult.score = _engine.Verify(((CData)lbDatabase.SelectedItem).EngineUser, 20000, out verificationResult.engineStatus);

        }
            args.Result = verificationResult;
    }
```

> Error: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'lbDatabase' accessed
>   from a thread other than the thread it was created on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three places in your code where you access `lbDatabase`.

1. The loop - `lbDatabase.Items.Count`
2. Setting the selected item - `lbDatabase.SelectedItem = i`
3. Retrieving the selected item - `lbDatabase.SelectedItem`

I assume on the second one you meant to write `lbDatabase.SelectedIndex = i`.

Only the second one you are invoking. So the other two are running on the background worker thread. That's why you're getting the error.

All access to UI elements - reading and writing - needs to be done on the UI thread.

Now, since you're trying to do this using a background worker you have a method that will freeze up the UI if it solely ran on the UI thread. So you need the parts that access the control to run on the UI, but everything else to run on the background thread.

The next problem is though, that calling `lbDatabase.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { lbDatabase.SelectedItem = i; }));` pushes the instruction to the UI, but there is no guarantee that the code will immediately run - in fact the entire loop might run and queue up all of the invokes. You obviously want it to happen synchronously, but that wont happen.

Looking at your code you clearly only want to access all of the `CData` items on the `lbDatabase` list box. There's a very easy way to make this work.

Just try this when calling the background worker:

```
backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(lbDatabase.Items.Cast<CData>().ToArray());
```

And then change your `doVerify` to this:

```
private void doVerify(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs args)
{
    CData[] items = (CData[])args.Argument;
    VerificationResult verificationResult = new VerificationResult();
    for (int i = 0; i < items.Length || verificationResult.score > 0; i++)
    {
        verificationResult.score = _engine.Verify(items[i].EngineUser, 20000, out verificationResult.engineStatus);
    }
    args.Result = verificationResult;
}
```

Comment: Hi, got a really big problem can we talk via skype? this code is from a project I'm making for a fingerprint reader using a DigitalPersona U.are.U 4500 using a sdk

Comment: The way i call this method is this: `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs taskResult = BusyForm.RunLongTask("Waiting for fingerprint ...", new DoWorkEventHandler(doVerify),
      false, ((CData)lbDatabase.SelectedItem).EngineUser, new EventHandler(CancelScanningHandler));`

Comment: there you can see how I call the doVerify method

Comment: @user2461687 - You need to show the code for `BusyForm.RunLongTask` and it's call in your question.

Comment: well It's kind of large, but I'll paste in the post

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329567/digital-persona-u-are-u-fingerprint-reader?noredirect=1#comment58367860_35329567   you can see this? is about the same code

Comment: @user2461687 - You need to show the source code for `BusyForm.RunLongTask` and not just its call. Or at least its signature and perhaps I can guess.

Comment: check again the link now there it is

Comment: @user2461687 - You need to learn to read code. The `((CData)lbDatabase.SelectedItem).EngineUser` parameter is passed through as the argument to the background worker. Which you're not using. Just replace it with `lbDatabase.Items.Cast<CData>().ToArray()` and my code should work.

Comment: it can't compile the error is that the listBox does not contain a definition for the cast

Comment: @user2461687 - `lbDatabase.Items` should though. If not make sure you've got a `using System.Linq;` at the top of your code.

Comment: for using the System.Linq do I need it to add as a reference ?

Comment: because I try to use only lbDatabase.Items but it gives me an error

Comment: @user2461687 - What do you mean `lbDatabase.Items` only? Without the `.Cast<CData>().ToArray()`?

Comment: @user2461687 - You shouldn't need to need to add any references to make `using System.Linq;` work.

Comment: yes I use only `lbDatabase.Items` without the cast because with the cast the red line appears under the cast

Comment: using only `lbDatabase.Items` it gives me the error when compile `'BusyForm' does not contain a definition for 'lblOperation_Click' and no extension method 'lblOperation_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'BusyForm' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: @user2461687 - Why would you only use `lbDatabase.Items`? You need to use `lbDatabase.Items.Cast<CData>().ToArray()` to make it work.

Comment: but visual marks it like an error in the part of `.Cast<CData>()`

Comment: I really don't know why it doesn't recognize the `.Cast`

Comment: @user2461687 - `Cast` is part of LINQ. It's required to turn the `IEnumerable` that is `Items` into an `IEnumerable<CDara>` so that `.ToArray()` can turn it into `CData[]`. See if you can find it on `System.Linq.Enumerable.Cast`.

Comment: it works but now I get another error  `Delegate to an instance method cannot have null 'this'.` I'm searching a solution for this.

Comment: it compiles now and checks but I don't know why the cycle for doesn't stop when a condition is reached

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103169/discussion-between-enigmativity-and-user2461687).

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty self explantory. You're running on a different thread, so you can't interact with the control. This means accessing `lbDatabase.Items.Count` is out.

If instead you:

```
lbDatabase.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => {
    VerificationResult verificationResult = new VerificationResult();
    for (int i = 0; i < lbDatabase.Items.Count || verificationResult.score > 0; i++)
    {
        lbDatabase.SelectedItem = i;  
        verificationResult.score = _engine.Verify(((CData)lbDatabase.SelectedItem).EngineUser, 20000, out verificationResult.engineStatus);
    }
    args.Result = verificationResult;
}));
```

then you'd probably be back in business. Now ***all*** of the accesses to the control are queued to run on the UI thread (and you're no longer switching contexts with `Invoke` in the middle of a loop... costly).

Comment: it brings me an error: Cannot convert lambda expression to type Delegate because it's not a delegate type

Comment: @user2461687 My bad. Fixed.

Comment: it compiles but when I use the method the program gets freezed

Comment: It does seem a bit counter-intuitive to run a background worker and then push the entire code back on to the UI thread.